# IE6 connection interruption in Comet streaming

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, internet-explorer-6

I am using a [forever frame](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/) ([COMET streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technique) and in IE6 whenever a user clicks on a link (to even just basic JavaScript method) the connection is immediately dropped and has to be manually refreshed.

Has anyone come across a similar issue and / or know how to address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to address it: `return false` from your event handlers (`event.preventDefault` for listeners etc) so that the link is not followed and so no navigation occurs on a simple left-click. Put all your logic in event handlers attached from script (and not `javascript:` URL, which are a horrible fragile hack that should never be used).

Further: if it's just a button that does some scripting when clicked, and doesn't actually point to anywhere usefully navigable, *it shouldn't be marked up as a link*. Ideally it should be a button (`input` or `button` with `type="button"`), which you can then use CSS to style like a link rather than a button if you prefer.

(Another approach, that requires less styling work but has accessibility drawbacks, is to do what SO does and just put an `onclick` event on a `<span>` or `<div>`.)